# Can a Organisation read implicit data collection of another Organization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to use implicit private data collection for a private transaction between 2 Organizations.
From the "asset transfer" fabric sample, I understand an Organization can write into the implicit data collection of another Organization.

Can an Organization read the implicit PDC of another Organization in some way?

Answer (score 1):

A user from OrganizationA can in theory read an OrganizationB PDC when calling chaincode on OrganizationB peer. It is the responsibility of OrganizationB to have access control logic in the chaincode running on their peer to indicate which users may read their private data.

In the [secured agreement sample](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/asset-transfer-secured-agreement/chaincode-go/asset_transfer.go), you can see access control that checks that user org matches peer org in the getClientImplicitCollectionName() utility function that is called in most chaincode functions. This ensures that only users from the peer's org can access the peer's private data.